# Duplicate First Value in PHP Array when Imploding

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM `likes`
        WHERE `pid` = $pid";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

$likers = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $likers[] = $row['uid'];
    echo implode(", ", $likers);
}

} else {
    return "Be the first to like this status...";
}
```

---

For example, it should display the following if the query results in 3 rows with the user IDs: **21, 20, 44**

It should display: **21, 20, 44**
But instead, it displays: **2121, 20, 44**
See how it displays the 1st value first?

Another example: **50, 60, 70**
But it displays: **5050, 60, 70**

Any way to fix? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are printing the result inside the `while` loop, thats why it is happening. First there will be 21 in the array, then it will be 21, 20 and so on.Print it outside the loop.Try with -

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $likers[] = $row['uid'];    
}

echo implode(", ", $likers);
```